# how to commit the change on Alpine?

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I followed that [tutorial](http://containertutorials.com/alpine/get_started.html) to pull the image and make it run on my docker

```
docker pull alpine
```

Then

```
docker run -it alpine /bin/sh
```

Once there, I do a

```
touch test.txt
```

However, once I'm exiting the container, <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd>, I cannot get back into it nor can I save the image with the changes.

Questions:

- What should I do to be able to get back to the images once I've done <kbd>Ctrl-P</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-Q</kbd> ?
- What should I do to commit the image to save my changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you never commit the changes at all (You can do that, but it is a huge antipattern)

If you want to modify a base image, simply write a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM alpine:3.5
touch test.txt
```

then on the command line: `docker build -t yourimagetag .`

If you want to share data (e.g. generated inside your docker container by your app) with your host system, take a look on docker volumes.